mutate() error - Index 1 must have length 1, not 13
My goal is to show multiple plots of residual vs. fitted values for a dataframe of 13 stations each having a separate lm() model. Working from an example in Chapter 25 (Many Models) in the R for Data Science (1st ed) textbook.
When running this line of R code (from Section 25.2.2 in the textbook)
by_stn <- by_stn %>% mutate(model = map(data, allstn_models))

...I receive the following error:
`Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `model = map(data, allstn_models)`.
ℹ In group 1: `station = s04029000`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `pluck_raw()`:
! Index 1 must have length 1, not 13.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.`

The structure of by_stn is:
# A tibble: 13 × 2
# Groups:   station [13]
   station   data              
   <fct>     <list>            
 1 s04029000 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 2 s04029990 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 3 s04030000 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 4 s04062011 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 5 s04063000 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 6 s04063700 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 7 s04064000 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 8 s04064500 <tibble [110 × 2]>
 9 s04065106 <tibble [110 × 2]>
10 s04066000 <tibble [110 × 2]>
11 s04066003 <tibble [110 × 2]>
12 s04066500 <tibble [110 × 2]>
13 s04067500 <tibble [110 × 2]>

The object allstn_models, a list of 13, is a set of lm() models for 13 different stations.
I went back to the example in the textbook and used the gapminder dataset and followed through with the example code. It worked without issue.
So I then thought to convert my original dataframe to a tibble. But that did not solve the problem.
How can I correct my error?

The syntax is map(<list>, <function>) to apply a function to each element of a list. From what you describe, allstn_models is not a function. I guess you need to make use of the predict function somehow, although it is not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Thank you. That solved it! Instead of allstn_models it should be the function stn_model (which exists). I appreciate your prompt help.
